# If $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ is càdlàg, does $t\mapsto x(t-)$ map compact sets to compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $E$ be a topological space and $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ be càdlàg. We can easily show that $x$ maps compact sets to compact sets. Now I would like to show that $x^-(t):=x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$ maps compact sets to compact sets as well. I know that we can show that $x^-$ is left-continuous. But is it also right-continuous? If that would be the case, we could conclude from the former result with $x$ replaced by $x^-$.

**EDIT**: I'm also interested in the case where $E$ is metrizable. In this case we can show that $x$ is bounded on every bounded interval. Does the same apply for $x^-$?

Comment: "We can easily show that $x$ maps compact sets to compact sets" -- How so?  If $x(t) = t$ for $t < 1$ and $x(t) = t+1$ for $t \geq 1$, then $x$ is càdlàg but $x$ maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$...

Comment: Unless I am mistaken: $x(t) = t$ for $t < 0$ and $x(t) = -1$ for $t \ge 0$ is càdlàg, and maps the compact interval $[-2, 0]$ to $[-2, 0)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Maybe I was too hasty. The result I've got in mind was that if $E$ is metrizable, then $x$ is bounded on every bounded interval.

Comment: Then I think what you actually want to show is that $x^-$ is right-limited (I cannot remember if it's called "càglàd" or "làdcàg" for this case), so that $(-\infty, 0] \to E : t \mapsto x^-(-t)$ is càdlàg.  It then shouldn't be hard to show that for metric spaces $E$, it takes compact sets to bounded sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the updated question:

If $t_0 \in [0, \infty)$ then $x(t)$ is close to $x(t_0-)$ or close to $x(t_0)$ for $t$ sufficiently close to $t_0$, so every $t_0$ has a neighborhood $U(t_0)$ on which $x(t)$ is bounded.

Then $x^-(t)$ is bounded on $U(t_0)$ as well.

Since every compact interval $I$ can be covered with finite many such neighborhoods $U(t_0)$, both $x(t)$ and $x^-(t)$ are bounded on $I$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we also show that $x^-$ is right-continuous? (At least at $0$?)

Comment: $x^-$ is not right-continuous in general: $x(t) = 0$ for $0 \le x < 1$ and $x(t)= 1$ for $x\ge 1$ is a counterexample. – Asking whether $x^-$ is right-continuous at $0$ does not make much sense in my opinion: How would you define $x^-(0)$?

Comment: By convention (as quite usual), $x(0-):=x(0)$. Please see [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4483694/47771).

Comment: With that definition is $x^-$ right-continuous at $0$: Since $x$ is right-continuous, $x(t)$ is close to $x(0)$ for sufficiently small $t > 0$, and then $x^-(t)$ is also close to $x(0)$.

Comment: Do you think my answer in the other question is correct and works for $s=0$ as well?