# If $x$ is càdlàg, is $t\mapsto x(t-)$ right-continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $E$ be a topological space, $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ be càdlàg and $$x^-(t):=x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s).$$ We can easily show that $x^-$ is left-continuous. But is it right-continuous as well?

If necessary, assume that $E$ is metrizable. And what I actually need is only right-continuity of $x^-$ at $0$. This might be easier, since (by definition) $x^-(0)=x(0)$.

**EDIT**: I've provided a [partial answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4483769/47771) below.

Comment: No, since $x^-(t+) = x(t+)$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan But if that's correct, shouldn't we have $x^-(0+)=x(0+)=x(0)=x^-(0)$, which is what I want to show?

Comment: This works only at time 0, because of the convention $x^-(0)=x(0)$. You could not define $x^-(0)$ as a left limit since $x$ is defined only on $[0,\infty)$. If you want a counterexample, look at what you obtain if $x$ is a sample path of a Poisson process, or even simpler $x(t) := 1_{[t \ge t_1]}$ where $t_1>0$ is fixed.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I'm intersted in how we show that $x^-(t+)=x(t+)$. However, in the particular case $t=0$, is there anything we need to show at all?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Please take note of my [(partial) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4483769/47771) below.

Comment: I answered your question with a counterexample and with a positive related result for metrisable spaces. I am not motivated to look at what happens in non-metrizable spaces.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan But the actual question *is* about non-metrizable spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137442/discussion-between-christophe-leuridan-and-0xbadf00d).

Answer (score 0):

### **Partial Answer**

As pointed out by [Christophe Leuridan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/421890/christophe-leuridan) below the question, we can show the following:

If the topology on $E$ is induced by a metric $d$, $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ be left- and right-regular and $s\ge0$, then $$x^-(s+)=x(s+)\tag1.$$

This can be proven in the following way: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $x$ is right-regular at $s$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$d(x(s+),x(t))<\frac\varepsilon2\tag2\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(s,s+\delta).$$ Let $u\in(s,s+\delta)$. Since $x$ is left-regular at $u$, there is a $\delta'\in(0,u-s)$ with $$d(x(t),x(u-))<\frac\varepsilon2\tag3\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(u-\delta',u).$$ Let $t\in(u-\delta',u)$. Since $$s<u-\delta'<t<u<s+\delta\tag4,$$ we can conclude $$d(x(s+),x^-(u))\le d(x(s+),x(t))+d(x(t)),x^-(u))\tag5<\varepsilon.$$

> Can we generalize this to the case of an arbitrary topological space $E$? And in the particular case of $s=0$ that I'm interested in, is there anything to prove at all?

Comment: I haven't inspected your proof in detail, but doesn't the example $x(t) = a$ for $0 \le t < t_0$ and $x(t) = b \ne a$ for $t \ge t_0$ clearly demonstrate that $x^-$ can be right-discontinuous at any $t_0 > 0$?

Comment: @MartinR Did you intend to write **cannot** instead of **can**? However, I'm not claiming that $x^-$ is right-continuous, but that the right-hand side limit of $x^-$ at $t$ is the right-hand side limit of $x$ at $t$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The title of your questions  asks if $x^-$ is right-continuous, and I am saying that that need not be the case. Am *I* misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, sure. What I meant was that this proof shows that $x^-$ is right-continuous at $0$. But I wondered wheter we actually need to "prove" this or if it's rather trivial for $s=0$.

Comment: That seems rather trivial to me: If $U \subset E$ is any neighborhood of $x(0)=x^-(0)$ then $x(t) \in U$ for $0 < t < \delta$, and that implies $x^(t) \in U$ for $0 < t < \delta$.

Comment: @Martin R $x(t) \in U$ for all $t \in (0,\delta)$ implies $x(t-) \in \overline{U}$ for all $t \in (0,\delta)$. So this argument concludes when $x(0)$ has a basis of closed neighborhoods.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan: Yes, you are right.